# communicating between javascripts and struts2 action

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have the following scenarios:

1. User will input some value , and this values will be validated against the value from DB in the action class.
2. If if the value is invalid, want to show a confirm box to the user whether he still want to proceed with the invalid value.
3. Depend on user's answer `YES` or `NO,` which is brought back to the action class, the process of the action class will be different.

For the above scenarios, step 1 is OK.

But how do I achieve to bring the value from the action class to the javascripts and getting user's confirmation and bring back the value to the action class?

Answer (score 0):

The second approach can be done by using Ajax. Struts 2 provides many ways to use Ajax:

1. Use the ["stream" result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/stream-result.html) to send data back to your JS code.
2. Use the [JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/json-plugin.html) to get JSON back.
3. Consider the [Struts 2 jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/).

A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=struts2%20and%20Ajax%20using%20jquery) will give you a lot of examples as how to use Ajax with Struts 2.